# How can I tell how many database connections my application is using?

Tags: grails, database-connection, grails-orm

I have a grails web application which is connecting to a Postgres database. I'm concerned that the code is opening multiple database connections.

How can I find out how many connections it is holding during a request?

There's a lot of magic going on in there with GORM etc and I'm not sure how it's managing its connections.

Answer (score 2):

It's managed by the `dataSource` bean, which is a `javax.sql.DataSource`. Unfortunately this interface is very basic, with only 4 methods - 2 `getConnection()` methods (one with and one without a username/password) and `unwrap` and `isWrapperFor` from its parent interface. The actual implementation classes typically have many different methods for configuration and monitoring, but there isn't really any standard, and definitely no interface.

If you're using a recent version of Grails and haven't reconfigured anything, the backing implementation is the [Tomcat JDBC Pool](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html), which doesn't depend on Tomcat but was written by a Tomcat committer. You can't just cast that bean to the pool implementation class however, because Grails wraps the actual datasource instance in two proxies. Fortunately the "real" instance is easy to get to - dependency-inject the `dataSourceUnproxied` bean in a service or wherever you wanted to look at usage:

```
def dataSourceUnproxied
```

and then you can call any of its methods (see [the Javadoc for what's available](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html))

It's not needed for Groovy of course, but if you want IDE autocompletion add this import

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
```

and cast it and call the methods on that, e.g.

```
DataSource tomcatDataSource = dataSourceUnproxied
log.debug "$tomcatDataSource.active active (max $tomcatDataSource.maxActive, initial $tomcatDataSource.initialSize), $tomcatDataSource.idle idle (max $tomcatDataSource.maxIdle, min $tomcatDataSource.minIdle)"
```